# SQL MAX of multiple columns and retrieve each row

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, union-all

I want to get the MAX value of close to 20 fields in my database. My issue is that I also want some other fields with all of these MAX values. I'm using PostgreSQL.

Here is an example:

**Match Table definition**

```
CREATE TABLE "matches" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('match_players_id_seq'::regclass),
    "kills" int4 NOT NULL,
    "deaths" int4 NOT NULL,
    "assists" int4 NOT NULL,
    "gamemode" int4 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

**Match table example data**

| id | kills | deaths | assists | gamemode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 12 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 7 | 2 | 27 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 4 | 27 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 |

```
INSERT INTO "matches" ("id", "kills", "deaths", "assists", "gamemode") VALUES
(1, 0, 0, 3, 1),
(2, 1, 0, 2, 2),
(3, 1, 12, 0, 3),
(4, 7, 2, 27, 1),
(5, 1, 4, 27, 2),
(6, 2, 3, 1, 3);
```

**Result I want (Table or JSON style) from the above data**

| what | amount | gamemode | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "kills" | 7 | 1 | 4 |
| "deaths" | 12 | 3 | 3 |
| "assists" | 27 | 1 | 4 |

```js
{
  "maxKills": {"id": 4, "kills": 7, "gamemode": 1},
  "maxDeaths": {"id": 3, "deaths": 12, "gamemode": 3}
  "maxAssists": {"id": 4, "assists": 27, "gamemode": 1} // Get the first one if 2 are equal
}
```

This is simplified. Here is a little pastebin to give you an idea of the real query: https://pastebin.com/eT8MNKKe
And another pastebin with the @Erwin answer's implementation: https://pastebin.com/2B8imJTj

I already posted this question two years ago but I used a NoSQL database (Mongo): [Get objects containing max values for multiple fields using aggregation in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59694730/9188650)

Here is my idea, I don't know if it's the best one:
Do 2 queries. The first one to get the MAX value of the 20 columns, and the second one to fetch the rows with a WHERE clause on the 20 aggregated MAX values. I'm just not sure how to do when multiple rows have the same MAX value.

Comment: Please review [ask]. You need to post your table definition (do not need the complete definition, just 3,4 columns you want the max values on) and some test data and the expected results of tat data, all as text - **no images**.   But I would take a guess that you could use the [window](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) version of the max function.  something like `max(kills) over (partition by id)` and repeat for each column name. That would only be 1 query.

Comment: First, thanks I will check these links. I did put my table definition ? It's markdown not an image. I updated the results I want from JS to JSON, it's maybe a little more clear.

Comment: Mark down is not a table definition, it is a description. I cannot copy/past and run a query against it.  Sorry, I guess I should have said post the table ddl.

Comment: I see! I have updated my question, I hope it's what you meant. It's the first time that I actually export data like this and I had to remove more than 40 fields so I hope it's not broken.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I did not. I was just asking for some more advices. The edits I did to my question were just to give more context as other people asked for.

Comment: @Kalane: Fair enough. I seem to have misunderstood. Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fastest and simplest:

```sql
(SELECT 'kills' AS what, kills, gamemode, id   FROM matches ORDER BY kills DESC, id LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'deaths'       , deaths, gamemode, id  FROM matches ORDER BY deaths DESC, id LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'assists'      , assists, gamemode, id FROM matches ORDER BY assists DESC, id LIMIT 1)
--  more ...
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9f7e5f9a8691371a1d744780aba73ea5)*

Add `id` as second `ORDER BY` expression. This way, if multiple rows tie for the highest score, the row with the smallest `id` is chosen.

All parentheses are required. See:

- [Combining 3 SELECT statements to output 1 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348755/combining-3-select-statements-to-output-1-table/59349080#59349080)
- [Create a unique index on a non-unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171623/create-a-unique-index-on-a-non-unique-column/29172960#29172960)

If any of the `ORDER BY` columns can be `NULL`, add `NULLS LAST`. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the rows with the maximum values. A SQL result is a table consisting of columns and rows. This is a pure SQL approach:

```
select what, amount, gamemode, id
from
(
  select id, gamemode, 'kills' as what, kills as amount, max(kills) over () as max_amount from mytable
  union all
  select id, gamemode, 'deaths' as what, deaths as amount, max(deaths) over () as max_amount from mytable
  union all
  select id, gamemode, 'assists' as what, assists as amount, max(assists) over () as max_amount from mytable
  union all
  ...
) all_candidates
where amount = max_amount;
```

There may be some JSON function build in to convert this result to JSON. I don't know. Maybe others can answer this.

Comment: The JSON was just an example because I'm not sure how to display SQL response in text. Thanks I will check that. Is it still something "ok" to do union all like this If I have more than 20 fields to MAX ?

Comment: Yes. The task is not very common, but if you want all the maximum row(s) per column, then you can use `UNION ALL` to glue them all together for a final data set. This is probably the easiest approach.

Comment: As mentioned, a SQL query result is a table. You are showing the matches table in your result, so you know how to show a table in a request. You should show the result table just the same.

Comment: True, I have updated my question with the idea coming from your answer.

Comment: Just one more question. How would you deal when multiple rows have the same max value ? For now your answer gets it both but I need only one. I tried to add ``LIMIT 1`` at the end of the 3 select subqueries you made but I have syntax error. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `row_number() over (order by kills desc) as rn` (same for deaths etc.) and then replace `where amount = max_amount` by `where rn = 1`. This is a ranking without considering ties. You only keep one row (per column) you rank first.

Comment: Okok thanks, I'm just now wondering as I said to Belayer: is it a lot better than just 20 oldschool queries ? Because I think I oversimplified the problem: I need to make 2 join per query to get columns I need and to add multiple where clauses to filter the data I'm looking at. The entire query takes 40ms (against like 2ms for simplier queries) on an almost empty database so I'm a little concerned.

Comment: Here is a little pastebin so that you can have an idea of the real query: https://pastebin.com/eT8MNKKe

Answer (score 1):

Perfect. You can use window version of max as I suspected. The only real difficulty was devising something to partition it on and not get the value for each row.

```
select m.*
     , max(m.kills )    over () max_kills
     , max(m.deaths )   over () max_deaths
     , max(m.assists )  over () max_assists
     , max(m.gamemode ) over () max_gamemode  
 from matches m;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=431f35b9dfda8e92283239a0e4c7e4af). For demo I added a couple of columns just to show the inclusion of 'other columns', but did not populate them.  

NOTE: Not directly related but you should avoid double quotes (") on database names. Once used they *must always* be used. It is just not worth the effort.

Comment: You can remove the `partition by` clauses. If there is nothing you want to group by then just leave the parentheses empty. The advice concerning the double quotes is very good.

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner. I knew that, just sometimes the brain does not go all the way. Kalane I have updated reply to what Thorsten in saying.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think the issue with this solution is that if I have 2M rows, the result will give me 2M rows too right ? Instead of for example 20 if I do the max on 20 fields.

By the way the quotes were generated by TablePlus when I made the exportation but thanks for the advice!

Comment: That would be correct. I guess I misunderstood what you ment by "some other fields " If you want **only** the max of certain them only select those, or just use a standard MAX function on each.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've updated my question with Thorsten idea. I'm now wondering if it's a lot better than just 20 oldschool queries.

Because I think I oversimplified the problem: I need to make 2 join per query to get columns I need + add multiple where clauses to filter the data I'm looking at.