# UNION ALL Slower than N queries

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, union-all

This question is following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69199076/sql-max-of-multiple-columns-and-retrieve-each-row) where I wanted to select the MAX value of multiples fields while retrieving each row.

The accepted answer with `UNION ALL` worked like a charm but I now have some scaling issues.

To give some context, I have more than 3 million rows in my matches table and the filters used in the `WHERE` condition can reduce this dataset to about 5000-6000 rows. I'm using **PostgreSQL**.

[The query](https://pastebin.com/BGDxE6C3) takes something like 14-16 seconds to process. The strange thing is that if I run one query at a time, it will take 150ms.

So if my maths are corrects, the total duration of this query should be 150ms * 20 (number of fields to select max value) = 3 seconds, not 16 ??

Why the entire query takes so much time ?

Here are some questions I have about that:

- Is it just better to do 20 queries and aggregate the final result ?
- Can I speed up my query by using some index ?
- Is it possible to make the WHERE filters + JOIN only once instead of doing it in all my queries ?

PS: here is the Node.js code I use if you want to read the query in a more readable way than the 500 lines of the pastebin:

```js
const fields = [
  'match_players.kills',
  'match_players.deaths',
  'match_players.assists',
  'match_players.gold',
  'matches.game_duration',
  'match_players.minions',
  'match_players.kda',
  'match_players.damage_taken',
  'match_players.damage_dealt_champions',
  'match_players.damage_dealt_objectives',
  'match_players.kp',
  'match_players.vision_score',
  'match_players.critical_strike',
  'match_players.time_spent_living',
  'match_players.heal',
  'match_players.turret_kills',
  'match_players.killing_spree',
  'match_players.double_kills',
  'match_players.triple_kills',
  'match_players.quadra_kills',
  'match_players.penta_kills',
]

const query = fields
  .map((field) => {
    return `
  (SELECT
      '${field}' AS what,
      ${field} AS amount,
      match_players.win as result,
      matches.id,
      matches.date,
      matches.gamemode,
      match_players.champion_id
  FROM
      match_players
  INNER JOIN
      matches
  ON
      matches.id = match_players.match_id
  WHERE
      match_players.summoner_puuid = :puuid
      AND match_players.remake = 0
      AND matches.gamemode NOT IN (800, 810, 820, 830, 840, 850, 2000, 2010, 2020)
  ORDER BY
      ${field} DESC, matches.id
  LIMIT 
      1)
  `
  })
  .join('UNION ALL ')

const { rows } = await Database.rawQuery(query, { puuid })
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Which SQL engine is behind this? You could maybe use a common table expression?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database engine and API support common table expressions (`WITH` keyword), then you could first perform the query that makes the join and the filtering, and then use the result set for performing the `UNION ALL`:

```js
const query = `
    WITH base as (
        SELECT 
            ${fields.join()},
            match_players.win as result,
            matches.id,
            matches.date,
            matches.gamemode,
            match_players.champion_id
        FROM
            match_players
        INNER JOIN
            matches
        ON
            matches.id = match_players.match_id
        WHERE
            match_players.summoner_puuid = :puuid
            AND match_players.remake = 0
            AND matches.gamemode NOT IN (800, 810, 820, 830, 840, 850, 2000, 2010, 2020)
    )
    ` + fields.map((field) => `
      (SELECT
          '${field}' AS what,
          ${field.split(".").pop()} AS amount,
          result,
          id,
          date,
          gamemode,
          champion_id
      FROM
          base
      ORDER BY
          2 DESC, id
      LIMIT
          1)
      `).join(' UNION ALL ');
```

Comment: Really impressive! The query only takes 200ms instead of 15s, thanks a lot you are a life saver ! I need to check more in details these CTE, it looks really powerful!